# Designing a suite of web applications

Tags: .net, azure, architecture, software-design

We are rewriting an enterprise legacy suite of applications that used to be written in Delphi. The suite consists of a few FAT clients used by power users, a single tenant relational database, a windows service web application used by all employees and a bunch of .EXE tools run on demand or scheduled. This suite was always installed onpremise (at a customer site) and was mostly limited to its LAN.

As it is 2018, we have to rewrite the suite into a web interface application. But not only that, we have to design it so that it is easily installed onsite, hosted by us or offered as SaaS in a multi-tenant kind of way. We also have some own HW onsite with every installation.

We've already started by decoupling the web app into the engine, web api (.NET Web API 2) and frontend SPA (Angular 2). We'll be using MQTT and Azure Iot Hub for communicating with our onpremise HW.

We are struggling with avoiding a single monolithic codebase for the new web application that will be replacing multiple legacy components now while at the same time not wanting to end up with what we had before: a mirriad of apps & tools with different usages, compatibilities, technologies written in, etc.

Specifically, we have several design doubts:

1. Do we break the application into several web applications (modules) that are fairly standalone and based around our own SSO server to provide authorization and authentication? We do want a seamless experience for users, especially the power users having access to practically all modules. Hence a single "portal" is a must-have.
2. Do we go for multitenant DB or rather use Azure elastic DB pools and have one DB per tenant in a SaaS environment?
3. Distribution: the suite is fairly complex to install and based on .NET framework (rather than .NET core), MS licensing simply does not offer a good way of providing appliances. Installers are so 1990. Docker is not really an option with onpremise installations.

Comment: For #1, look into microservices architecture. #2, if you need to support it, you should design multitenancy from the get-go including in your application layer/service contracts.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning, I have microservices on the radar.

Answer (score 1):

Never, ever, rewrite a large application from scratch.  Doing so is almost always [doomed to failure](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/).  There are several tools that allow you to write restful services on top of Delphi like [this](https://www.embarcadero.com/developing-rest-servers-in-delphi-xe-using-datasnap).

I would pick the most common modules, write web front ends on top of these services, reduce your installation costs.   Then once you have a critical mass of front-ends, work on rewriting the back-ends to ease your installation costs (and introduce multi-tenancy).

Doing this gradually will not only give you the advantage of the existing application infrastructure, it will relieve the largest issue a major rewrite presents, which is "how much do we need before we launch"?  This question generally paralyzes a software organization, as management generally asserts that the new app must do everything the old one did, plus some additional features.  The problem is, the old app was written over 10 years, and for some reason, they aren't willing to wait 10 years for the new one to be built.

If you are going to go for a big-bang rewrite, make sure you spend a bunch of time establishing your scope before you start writing code.

Comment: Thanks Rob. We are aware of the issues presented in Spolsky's blogpost. Still, the question remains on how to write new web frontends to avoid a behemoth codebase but at the same time allow for seamless user experience.